# Why can't I attach javascript to my html?

Tags: javascript, html

No matter how I choose to add a javascript file to a html file, it doesn't seem to work. My original code is longer and has more stuff in it but I thought I would isolate the problem and see if with a very basic bit of code I would get the same problem (which I do).

I've tried adding the script tag to the head and to the body (at the start and at the end).

Brackets states that the function is never called and also seems to think that alert doesn't exist. If I add internal javascript it works.

in Chrome's console it reads:

```
test.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: helloWorld is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test.html:1) onclick @ test.html:1
```

when I click the button.

HTML is:

```
<!doctype>
<head>
    <title>testcode</title>
    <script src="test.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="helloWorld()">Press to say hello world</button>
</body>
```

test.js is in the same folder and is:

```
function helloWorld() {
    alert("Hello World!");
}
```

UPDATE: I changed nothing and just reopened the browser, now it works (currently missing python a lot).

Comment: can you specify the both relative path?

Comment: How are you testing this? It appears to be that your script doesn't get loaded. If you just save that HTML and then double click on the file, the browser won't download the `test.js` file. Try testing this with a local web server such as `serve`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve

Comment: I copy and paste your code and put in both files the same folder, without local web server, everything works.

Comment: Is that the **ONLY** Javascript in the file? A mistake at the top could make the entire script invalid (ex. extra open bracket)

Comment: @ArashMotamedi What do you mean? The browser is perfectly capable of running JavaScript in files. Try it yourself. I build all sorts of web games without uploading them to my server, often with four or five external JS files linked in the `<head>`.

Comment: Check the Network tab in chrome developer tools to check if the `test.js` file is being downloaded correctly.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Interesting, I may be rusty in remembering how browsers treat local files. So, no need to reference those scripts with a `file:///...` style path?

Comment: I'm testing this using brackets live preview feature. What I'm finding interesting is Brackets gives me a error saying that the function is never called within the project. This made me wonder if it was something incorrect prior to previewing it. In terms of errors when previewing the code 

```
webSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:20184/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: @ArashMotamedi Nope, file names work just like they would on a hosted website

Answer (score 0):

The code is working for me. Maybe it's the path of the files. If the files are in the same level, it should works..

```
- index.html
- test.js
```

But if the script is in a folder, you should change the script tag. Exemple :

```
- index.html
- /js
    - test.js
```

`<script src="js/test.js"></script>`

There is another case, if your html page is `/article/hello` and your js `/test.js` you should change the script tag with `<script src="../test.js"></script>`

Comment: Both files are in the same directory. My original code had them divided into different directories but for the purposes of getting a very simple bit working I made this as simple as I could.

Answer (score -2):

It's working for me. I just copied and pasted your exact code and it was working for me. Make sure you have saved both html and js files in same directory.

In order to check if JS file is included just open Developers Options (Ctrl+Shift+I) in chrome and then see if you get any  [error like this(in case js file was not included)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U20kz.png)